# Can I use Bash features in an RPM spec file?

Tags: bash, rpm, rpmbuild

Searching [open source projects](http://google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q=%22while%20read%22%20file%3a%5C.spec%24&sbtn=Search), shows me that spec files in the wild do use bash constructs, for instance `cat info|while read`.

But is it really safe? Does the rpm documentation tells me I can count on the `%build` section being run by `Bash`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default shell invoked for each of the spec stanzas is given by `%_buildshell`. This defaults to `/bin/sh`, but can be overridden either globally or on a per-stanza basis.

Comment: Will it gracefully fail, if I point to `/bin/bash`, but it doesn't exist?

Comment: No. The shell in use must exist.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **yes**

Long answer: While bash has become the *de facto* standard of Linux shells and in practice you can count on having bash around, it does not hurt to specify `%_buildshell` to `/bin/bash` as already mentioned in @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams 's answer

Comment: Attempting to use process substitution or herestrings *without* switching the shell will fail. So no.